# Stack to --> ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, stack

I made a Stack and an ArrayList to make a research. Actually I want now to make my Stack replaced by an ArrayList, but how to transform a Stack into an ArrayList ? How is it going with push, pop ... ?

```
public static ArrayList<State> search(State finalstate)
{
    ArrayList<State> toreturn = new ArrayList<State>();
    Stack<State>mystack=new Stack<State>();
    mystack.push(initState);
    State currState;
    currState=initState;
    while(!mystack.isEmpty() && !currState.equals(finalstate) )
    {
        currState=mystack.pop();
        toreturn.add(currState);
        if(currState.vecinos.containsKey("up"))
        {
            mystack.push(currState).vecinos.get("up");
        }
        if(currState.vecinos.containsKey("down"))
        {
            mystack.push(currState).vecinos.get("down");
        }
        if(currState.vecinos.containsKey("left"))
        {
            mystack.push(currState).vecinos.get("left");
        }
        if(currState.vecinos.containsKey("right"))
        {
            mystack.push(currState).vecinos.get("right");
        }
    }
    
    return toreturn;
}
```

Comment: Well `pop` removes items from a `Stack`, and `push` adds items to a `Stack`. Why are you adding items to your `Stack` while copying to the `List`? What do you want in your `List` when the method completes?

Comment: Just to keep a trace of it in the List

Comment: just to keep a track* sorry

Comment: What does that mean? You're modifying the `Stack` while you copy it... that is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 35):

Stack is a Collection, you can use ArrayList(Collection) constructor

```
list = new ArrayList(stack);
```

Comment: This is problematic. If we pushed stuff into Stack in this order: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, then surprisingly the ArrayList will also end up as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] whereas we probably expect [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Comment: Yup, @Wei is right, this method results in reverse order for stack.

Comment: Collections.reverse(stack); // resolves the issue :)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way I've found to convert a Stack into a List is using the following line:

```
List<Integer> stackToList = new ArrayList(stack);
```

However, this yields the stack reversed. 
Meaning, if your stack was **1, 2, 3** you would expect in the list **3, 2, 1** because that's the order the stack objects would be "popped". That's not the case though instead, you get **1, 2, 3**. So, in order to get the expected output, you need to execute

```
Collections.reverse (stackToList);
```

This will reverse the list inline and give you **3, 2, 1**

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is not right, as the order will be reverse.
Instead you can just *iterate* like this:

```
Stack<State> stack = new Stack<>();
List<State> list = new ArrayList<>();
while(!stack.isEmpty()) { 
    list.add(stack.pop()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayDeque from Deque interface can be used for this type of operation.

ArrayDeque is better to used then Stack.

```java
Deque<Integer> d = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
d.push(10);
d.push(20);
d.push(30);

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(d);
System.out.println(d.toString());
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Deque instead,

```
Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
deque.push(1);
deque.push(2);
deque.push(3);
System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(deque)); // 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: I can convert the stack into an array-list with this line.